# Python: strptime on a string with missing data

Tags: python, strptime

I'm trying to convert a specific type of string that conveys an amount of time into datetime format. The strings follow the format `1d2h3m4s`, as in 1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes, and 4 seconds.

I'm currently doing it this way: `timeobject = datetime.strptime(time, '%dd%Hh%Mm%Ss')`
It works perfect as long as the string is in that format. The only problem is that sometimes some of the values are left out, so it'll be something like `2h3m`. This doesn't work because it doesn't match the format: `ValueError: time data '2h3m' does not match format '%dd%Hh%Mm%Ss'`

What I'm looking for is to add a zero into the missing spots so that this no longer happens, e.g. change `2h3m` into `0d2h3m0s`, unless there is another solution available, in which case I'm all ears!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fix your string as requested, you can use a regex to extract each element and replace the missing ones with a default value:

```
import re

time = '2h3m'
out = re.search('(\d+d)?(\d+h)?(\d+m)?(\d+s)?', time).groups()
default = ('0d', '0h', '0m', '0s')
time2 = ''.join(a if a else b for a,b in zip(out, default))
```

Output: `'0d2h3m0s'`

*NB or is not fully clear which output you expect from datetime as zero days are not correct, but you can easily adapt the above code*

###### alternative getting numbers

You can also extract numbers to use directly in the datetime/timedelta constructor:

```
import re

time = '2h3m'
out = re.search('(\d+d)?(\d+h)?(\d+m)?(\d+s)?', time).groups()
default = (1, 0, 0, 0)
time2 = [int(a[ :-1]) if a else b for a,b in zip(out, default)]
```

Output: `[1, 2, 3, 1]`

###### timedelta

Example with the timedelta constructor:

```
from datetime import timedelta 

import re
time = '2h3m'
out = re.search('(\d+d)?(\d+h)?(\d+m)?(\d+s)?', time).groups()
default = (0, 0, 0, 0)
d, h, m, s = [int(a[ :-1]) if a else b for a,b in zip(out, default)]
timedelta(d, h*3600+m*60+s)
```

Output: `datetime.timedelta(seconds=7380)`